# Thread name convention in spring kafka ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer consumerr

Tags: spring-kafka

I am using spring-kafka to consume from topic and we are using ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.

Below is my application.yml

```js
spring:
  kafka:
    listener:
      concurrency: 2
    consumer:
      group-id: test-consumer-group
      topic: CONSUMER-TOPIC
```

In log we can see thread name is printed as test-consumer-group-0-C-1.

> 2021-10-04 11:04:41.254 [test-consumer-group-0-C-1]

I have checked below file to arrive how this thread name is arrived.

- ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer
- KafkaMessageListenerContainer

Here the thread name is like this  [group-id]-[concurrency]-C-X.
Unable to understand how this X is arrived at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well explained in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-thread-naming

> So, with a bean name of container, threads in this container will be named `container-0-C-1`, `container-1-C-1` etc., after the container is started the first time; `container-0-C-2`, `container-1-C-2` etc., after a stop and subsequent start.

So, the `X` in your equation belongs to the thread number when it is obtained from an executor to handle `KafkaConsumer` interaction. See `CustomizableThreadCreator`:

```
/**
 * Return the thread name to use for a newly created {@link Thread}.
 * <p>The default implementation returns the specified thread name prefix
 * with an increasing thread count appended: e.g. "SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-0".
 * @see #getThreadNamePrefix()
 */
protected String nextThreadName() {
    return getThreadNamePrefix() + this.threadCount.incrementAndGet();
}
```

Comment: Actually there is a bug; while the last digit should increment each time the container is stopped/started, it is not - it is always 1 - we always create a new `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` when starting the child containers. You can specify your own executor with whatever naming strategy you would like. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1974

Comment: We probably should cache that `new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor()` on the first `doStart()` call.

Comment: A GH issue for mentioned bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1974